# Выбора MySQL (поиск)

Tags: mysql

Есть столбец с данными: 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2

Как сделать запрос MySQL что бы узнать что "5" в базе нет, при условии что мы будем смотреть от максимального значения к нулю с шагом 1 ?

Comment: У SQL нет понятия направления поиска по той причине что нет понятия каких либо циклов. Единственный способ узнать что числа нет, это задать явный вопрос "действительно ли числа нет", например вроде `select count(1) from tab where col=5` и посмотреть полученное кол-во, или, если надо проверить это в другом запросе воспользоваться явным "нет в таблице" - "not exists" `select 1 where not exists(select 1 from tab where col=5)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(t1.val) - 1 AS largest_absent
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.val = 1 + t2.val
WHERE t2.val IS NULL
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните свой ответ. Откуда взялась вторая таблица? В вопросе ее не было.

Comment: Это не две таблицы, а две копии одной таблицы.

Comment: Из чего я должен был сделать такой вывод? В вашем ответе пояснений нет, а в вопросе вообще никакие таблицы не упоминаются. Допустим t1 - это таблица со столбцом из вопроса. Откуда взялась копия?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Такой вывод можно сделать увидев в from `table t1`, таблица в примере называется table, а t1 это ее алиас в данном запросе. И в join то же самое имя `table`, только с другим алиасом, что является обычной (и единственно возможной) практикой при объединении таблицы с самой собой

Comment: @Mike Я интерпретировал вопрос автора так: найти максимальное целое меньше максимального значения в столбце, которое отсутствует в этом столбце.